# Vue `defineModel` returned value is object or array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

`defineModel()` is introduced in Vue 3.4+. In the [official doc](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup#definemodel), it has the following example:

```js
const model = defineModel()
model.value = 'hello'
```

At this point I think `model` is an object with `value` property.

Then later it has the following example:

```js
const [modelValue, modelModifiers] = defineModel()
```

Now I am a bit confused, it seems in this case the returned value from `defineModel()` is an array with `modelValue` and `modelModifiers` as its items.

How should I comprehend the above examples? I know there must be some "magic" happening under the hood, but to this point I am not sure what is actually happening.

Anyone can provide me with more explanation / info ? Thanks.

Comment: `defineModel` is a macro, don't look at it like it's an actual javascript function - because, it isn't

Comment: Technically "model" could be both in JS by implementing iterator protocol. But it doesn't have to because it's compiler macro, as said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joromanda X replied in the comments, it's a Vue script setup macro and should be seen as 'it just works'.

But if you want to know the details (I did so I looked it up):

In Javascript a regular object can also be an [interator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). The macro turns your `defineModel` function call into a different function (`useModel`, see [here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/runtime-core/src/helpers/useModel.ts) for the implementation).

This function returns an object which is a Vue `ref` (so you can use `.value`), but is also an iterator, so when you [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) using the array syntax, you can access both the model and the modifiers. The first object returned by the iterator is the combined ref/iterator itself.

Comment: nice details to know

Comment: Thanks for all the info! I will accept the answer first. Sorry I don't have time to read all the reference links yet but I will read them when I have time.